# ElectronJS - webcontents.on 'did-finish-load' vs 'dom-ready' vs 'ready-to-show'

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

It seems like if you call `loadFile` on your `BrowserWindow` and then call `webContents.send` inside a `webContents.on("did-finish-load")` clause, your data will be sent and captured, but not with `dom-ready` or `ready-to-show`.

Why is that?

I've read the docs, and it didn't seem too helpful.

Comment: please show your example, which fails to send message on 'dom-ready' (it should work)